# I have to click 3 times on datalist to select item

Tags: html

I don't know if this behavior is normal...

```html
<input list="options" onchange="console.log(this.value)" value="datalist"/>
<datalist id="options">
  <option value="1" >Foo</option>
  <option value="2">Bar</option>
  <option value="3">Foo</option>
</datalist>

<input id="test" value="test"/>
```

When you execute this code, the first input ( which using datalist ), you have to click 3 times quickly to select the word "datalist", but on the second input ( a normal input) you have to click on it 2 times.

When I say I click, I click at the end of the word, just after the last letter!

This is normal ? There is a way to bypass this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Works exaclty the same in both cases. Double-click and the word is selected. Just running the snippet as posted.

Comment: really? Are you using chrome? Ahhh I understand ! You click on the word, and I click at the end of the word ! This behavior is strange, I am afraid that some of my clients find it unpleasant. But I think there is no solution

Comment: Ah, I see. I was using Safari on macOS. It works with two clicks regardless if I click the word itself, or off the end of the word. BUT, in Edge (which is Chromium-based) I see the behavior that you describe. I don't think anything can be done about it. It's deep inside the browser code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! :)I hope my clients won't mind, otherwise I won't use datalist

Answer (score 0):

Hey so there are a couple of issues in this approach

```
<input list="options" onchange="console.log(this.value)" value="datalist"/>
<datalist id="options">
  <option value="1" >Foo</option>
  <option value="2">Bar</option>
  <option value="3">Foo</option>
</datalist>

<input id="test" value="test"/>
```

setting the value to datalist make the datalist always display datalist all the time and not showing any other options the best way to do the thing that you want which i persume is a drop down select is just to use select as follows:

```
<select class="form-control" name="options" onselect="console.log(this.value)">
  <option value="1" >Foo</option>
  <option value="2">Bar</option>
  <option value="3">Foo</option>
</select>
```

hope that is helpful.